# Using sed to replace numbers with '@' inserts '@' between every character

Tags: sed

I want to replaced all number with '@' symbol. I am using the below sed command , but not getting the desired result.

command -

```
echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" | sed 's/[0-9]*/@/g'
```

Result -

```
@a@b@c@ @ @p@a@n@k@a@j@ @
```

Comment: `echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" | sed 's/[0-9]/@/g'`

Answer (score 8):

Well, quite simply, `[0-9]*` matches strings that consist entirely of *zero or more* digits, include empty strings. Anything that matches an empty string, matches between any two characters, so the replacement `@` is added between all letters in the input. Strings of multiple digits are replaced with one `@` since the expression matches all consecutive digits at once.

So in the input string `ab43` the matches to `[0-9]+` are (with some whitespace added for clarity):

```
    a   b   434
  ^   ^     ^^^- here, a string of some digits
  ^   ^- here, a zero-length string
  ^- here, a zero-length string
```

Use `[0-9]` to match exactly one digit, or `[0-9][0-9]*` to match one or more (or `[0-9]+` in extended regular expressions).

Comment: then the regex pattern should replace all alphabets with '@' symbols, since alphabets has zero digits.

Comment: @PankajPandey, err, right. I rephrased that a bit.

Comment: @PankajPandey, should they be? Neither `[0-9]*` nor `[0-9]` match any letters, and I thought you wanted to replace only numbers?

Comment: by that logic, alphabetic characters should also be replaced by '@' since they also do not match to any of the digits.

Comment: i just want to understand the behaviour of sed command, as I feel it's behaviour is somewhat erratic.

Comment: @PankajPandey, yeah, I'm not sure if I can rephrase that in readable English without any other loopholes. Part of the issue is that `s/pattern/repl/g` doesn't try to _match_ anything as much as _search_ for something that matches the pattern. It starts by looking at the first character (`a`) and asks "does this start a string of zero or more digits". The answer is "yes (there are exactly zero digits starting at this position)" so the replacement is added. Then it moves to the next letter, finds zero digits, places the replacement...

Comment: ...Then it looks at the position of the first `4`, where the answer is "yes, there are three digits starting at this position", and they all get replaced by the `@`. Patterns that match zero-length strings are not very useful (except as parts of larger patterns, of course)

Comment: It should also be noted, that quantifiers like `*`, and `+`, and others, are greedy by default. Hence the shortest string satisfying the regex will accept. The book "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl explains this quite well.

Comment: @polemon, shortest? Or do you mean longest? `[0-9]+` would match all the digits in something like `abc123def`, and not e.g. once for each digit or so. As compared to e.g. Perl's non-greedy modifiers, `perl -e 'print "$&\n" while "abc123def" =~ /[0-9]+/g'` vs. the same with `/[0-9]+?/`.

Comment: @ilkkachu it's greedy in both ways. The first time the state machine can accept it will do so. Once it finds the beginning of the expression, the machine will race ahead to the end of a strung and then "bump-back" to find the longest string. A good example is: `asdf "asdf asdf" asdf "asdf asdf" asdf`, if matching the string against `/".*"/`, it'll extract `"asdf asdf" asdf "asdf asdf"`. It'll greedily get the first, `"`, the race to the end, and then bump-back until it finds the last `"`. Again, this example is taken directly from the book I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each digit with `@`

```bsh
echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" | sed 's/[0-9]/\@/g'
#Output: abc @@@ pankaj @@@
```

or replace each `number` with `@`

```bsh
echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" | sed 's/[0-9]\+/\@/g'
#Output: abc @ pankaj @
```

depending on the desired output you need

Comment: Why escape the `@` in the replacement, and why `-E`? Also, why not `tr '0-9' '@'`? However, this would replace all digits with `@`, not all _numbers_. One could potentially read the question in a way that means that the wanted output should be `abc @ pankaj @`.

Comment: Note that `\+` is a GNU extension. The standard equivalent is `\{1,\}`. With `-E` (soon to be standard), you can use `+` or `{1,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace * with any special character can be achieved by using `tr` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
mystring="This is my number: 12345"
echo $mystring | sed 's/[0-9]/*/g'
```

Comment: `tr` is certainly one tool that can be used. But your example doesn't explain how - you used `sed`, not `tr`. Also your answer suggests that what OP wants to do requires a script and a variable - surely this is not what you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abc 434 pankaj 444"| tr "[0-9]" "@"

abc @@@ pankaj @@@
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to replace digits or whole numbers (runs of consecutive digits) with `@`, you may use the `tr` command without or with its `-s` option:

```
$ echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" | tr '[:digit:]' '[@*]'
abc @@@ pankaj @@@
```

```
$ echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" | tr -s '[:digit:]' '[@*]'
abc @ pankaj @
```

The `-s` option of `tr` makes the utility "squeeze" any consecutively occurring character from the second argument found in the data.  In this case, using `-s` makes `tr` combine runs of `@` characters into single `@` characters.

The two arguments `[:digit:]` and `[@*]` tell `tr` to replace digits with `@` characters.  Most (all?) implementations of `tr` allow you to write `@` in place of `[@*]` as the second argument.  The `[@*]` literally means "as many `@` as there are characters in the set described by the first argument".

Note that `tr` will squeeze any pre-existing runs of consecutive `@` characters in the input if `-s` is in effect.

---

Your approach with `sed` does not work as expected because you insert a `@` character wherever there are zero or more matches of a digit.  There are zero digits between each character in the input, so the expression matches between each character.

A modified substitution that would work correctly and replace runs of digits with a single `@` would be

```bsh
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\{1,\}/@/g'
```

By using `\{1,\}` in place of `*` (which in itself is the same as `\{0,\}`) we force at least one match of the preceding expression. You will see `\{1,\}` written as `+` in extended regular expressions.

By removing `\{1,\}` from the expression, leaving the substitution as `s/[[:digit:]]/@/g`, you replace each individual digit with a `@`.

Comment: Beware though that `echo @@123@@ | tr -s '[:digit:]' '[@*]'` outputs `@`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's a big whoops. I will add the necessary notices to the text.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by awk command too

---

```
echo "abc 434 pankaj 444" |awk '{gsub("[0-9]","@",$0);print $0}'
```

---

Comment: While true, `sed` is the right tool for the job and will work given a small modification.